# Executing multiple HTTP client request in node

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a backend app using `nodejs` which execute a lot of `http` requests to external services and `s3`.
I have reached to roughly 800 requests per second on a single kubernetes pod.
The pod is limited to a single vcpu and it has reached to 100% usage.

I can scale it to tens of pods to handle the execution of thousands of requests,
but it seems that this limit has reached too soon.

I have tested it in my real backend app and then on a demo pod which does nothing but to send `http` request using `axios`.

Does it make sense that a single vcpu kubernetes pod can only handle 800 req / sec? (as client and not as a server).

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to propose any advice for the best approach with choosing a proper capacity for the compute resources affordable to your specific needs. However, when you use `1x vCPU` in Pod limit requests it equivalents 1 CPU unit for most widely used Cloud providers VM resources.

Thus, I would bet here for adding more CPU units into your Pod than spinning more Pods with a same number of `vCPU` by Kubernetes scheduler using [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) (Horizontal Pod Autoscaler) feature. Therefore, if you don't have enough capacity on your node, it's very easy to push lots of Pod to be overloaded; and indeed this would not give positive influence on Node compute engine.

In your example, there are two key metric parameters to analyze: **latency** (time for sending requests and receiving answer) and **throughput** (requests per second) of `HTTP` requests; here is always the rule on the top: Increasing the latency will decrease the overall throughput for your requests.

You can also read about [Vertical Pod Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler) as an option for managing [compute resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/) in Kubernetes cluster.